# Setup mailx as Java SMTP Configuration

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp

I am trying to send email from a Java/Spring software. I'm using JavaMailSender of spring framework. How can I configure local machine as JavaMailSender's smtp host? I can send email via the following command:

```
echo “test123” | mailx -s “test mail” emailaddress@email.com
```

However, how can I write my mail.properties to support the command above?

This is my javaMailSender bean:

```
<bean id="javaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.smtp.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mail.smtp.port}" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="${mail.defaultEncoding}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.debug">${mail.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" >${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is mail.properties file:

```
mail.debug                = true
mail.defaultEncoding      = UTF-8
mail.smtp.host            = localhost
mail.smtp.port            = 25
mail.username             = 
mail.password             = 
mail.smtp.starttls.enable = false
mail.smtp.auth            = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that mailx is a mail client you need a mail server to do what you are looking for.

If this is a desktop development environment issue then have a look at [smtp4dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com)

Otherwise on a Unix system install smtpd or hook into exchange from a widows environment.